# show DatePickerDialog on Button click

Tags: android

I want to show a DatePickerdialog on button click ?
Now i tried this code :

```
  btn_end_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int myyear = c.DATE ;
            int mymonth = c.MONTH;
            int mydate = c.YEAR ;

            DatePickerDialog ddp = new DatePickerDialog( getApplicationContext(), new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_end_date.setText(year+"/"+monthOfYear +"/"+dayOfMonth );
                }
            }, myyear, mymonth,mydate);
            ddp.show();
        }
    });
```

But this gives me this error :

```
   android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception unable to add window
```

So , how can i do this correctly ?

Comment: use Activity context instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: how ? Please tell me i am beginner .

Comment: use ActivityName.this for using the activity context

Comment: @Rehamk use `ActivityName.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: thanks alot it works for me .
please post your answer as answer so that i can mark that as answer.